# MS Word OOXML style name issue

Tags: ms-word, xml-parsing, openxml

I have been searching for all the default styles in MS Word.

For some particular styles I noticed that the style name is different in MS Word Application UI and in OOXML.

e.g. insert some comment in Word document the style **w:styleId="CommentText"** is being populated in styles.xml. The name of this style in styles.xml is **'annotation text'** while in application no style with this name is present *(although style with name **Comment Text** is present in Applciation UI)*.

I searched for some mapping of **annotation text style** with **Comment Text style** but I didn't noticed any mapping.

Same scenario is replicable for **header** and **footer** style.

Name of these styles in Application are **'Header'** and **Footer** respectively (name with capital first letter).

I am trying to know how to map the style name in styles.xml with name in the application UI.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know the mapping of the names of the built-in styles to the style id used in Open XML you can create a sample document containing all the built-in styles and then check the Open XML of that file.

This macro will create a document with all built-in paragraph styles:

```
Sub CreateDocWithBuiltinStyles()

    Dim style As style
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim rng As Range

    Set doc = Application.Documents.Add
    Set rng = doc.Range

    For Each style In doc.Styles
        If style.BuiltIn And _
          (style.Type = wdStyleTypeParagraph Or _
           style.Type = wdStyleTypeLinked Or _
           style.Type = wdStyleTypeCharacter Or _
           style.Type = wdStyleTypeParagraphOnly) Then

            Set rng = doc.Range
            rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            rng.style = style
            rng.Text = style.NameLocal & vbCrLf

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You then have to examine the *document.xml* file in the generated package and you can easily see what display name belongs to what style id.